# Using function from minified .js (Google Closure) in Play 2.0

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, google-closure-compiler

I wanted to use Google Closure Compiler to to minimize javascript, but in minimized version it renames function names. Is this the intended behavior? How to use this in that situation ?

lib.js

```
function myfun() {
   $('#test').hide();
}
```

lib.min.js

```
function myfun$$module$main(){$("#test").hide()}
```

view

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfun()">no longer works</a>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?hl=en#export

Comment: I've read that... but i think can't use within play framework (how to set compiler options?)... maybe i'm wrong. I have not found the way how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, a few things you can do there, you could go:

1) window['functionName'] = functionName which will preserve it or

2) link in the closure library and use goog.exportSymbol

Comment: `window['functionName'] = functionName` works! I did not notice this before. Thank You.

Comment: another way is to declare an extern and pass that into the compiler, but externs should not be used in this way. effectively any string literal like this['jjjj'] will stop renaming

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the event handlers to the HTML elements within JavaScript so during the compilation process Google Closure can rename these functions as well. You can also use a simpler version of the optimization ([WHITESPACE_ONLY](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels)) that does not rename functions or expression.

Assign an ID to the HTML element: `<a href="#" id="link">does this work?</a>`.

And in your JavaScript, assign the event:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");
var myFun = function () {
    alert("hello world");
};
link.onclick = myFun;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: event handlers: Yes, You right, but this is not always possible or more complex than simple  `onclick="myfunc()"`. How to use another Google Closure optimization within Play2 ?

Comment: It is usually suggested to use HTML to provide the structure of the page and not the functionality. So I would avoid assigning event handlers within HTML tags as much as possible.

Comment: Yes you're right, but if you can do something easier, why not do it?

Comment: Well, easier approach is not always the best. It's always a trade-off, and in this situation, you will produce better quality code and also be able to run it through Google Closure and optimize it.